# Vuejs router transition doesn't happen

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I've just started learning vue and tried to do a router transition. However the above code doesn't have any transitions when I switch between pages. Any idea why?
Extra line since stackoverflow does not let me submit the question otherwise.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link><br><br>
    </div>
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

</script>
<style>
body {
  background-color: #00ffcc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(2em);
}

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .3 ease;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with your CSS code, it should be `transition: all 0.3s ease`.
Here is a working example

```js
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
const Foo = { template: '<div>Foo</div>' }

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'hash',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo }
  ]
})

new Vue({
    router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #00ffcc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}

.router-link-active {
  color: red;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(2em);
}

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/">/home</router-link>
  <router-link to="/foo">/foo</router-link>
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <router-view></router-view>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Here, is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/9y0dnhej/12/) of the above code .